# Is $\lim S_{n,m}=\sum_{k=1}^n({-1})^k{n\choose k}k^{-m}<\infty $ for $ n \to \infty$ and $m$ large?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, asymptotics, estimation

Let $m$ be a fixed positive integer ($m>1)$ and let $$S_{n,m}=\sum_{k=1}^n({-1})^k{n\choose k}k^{-m}$$ be a partial sum of real series.

My question here is : Is $\lim S_{n,m} <\infty $ as $ n \to \infty$?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: This is not well defined for $k=0$.

Comment: thank you for this observation, i edited it ,now it fixed

Comment: @zeraouliarafik The limit is always infinite as given in my answer below. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach to the asymptotics, as $n \to \infty$, of sums of the form
$$
S_n:=\sum_{k=1}^n({-1})^k{n\choose k}f_k \tag1
$$ is known as the technique of Rice's integrals. The idea is to represent the sum as an integral over an appropriate complex contour then evaluating it by the residue calculus. The residue computation applied here reduces to the following coefficient extraction:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n({-1})^k{n\choose k}\frac1{k^m}=-[s^m]\frac1{\left(1-\dfrac{s}1 \right)\left(1-\dfrac{s}2 \right)\cdots \left(1-\dfrac{s}n \right)} \tag2
$$
and we get, for $m\geq2$, as $n \to \infty$,

> $$
> -\sum_{k=1}^n({-1})^k{n\choose k}\frac1{k^m}=P_m(\log n)+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{(\log n)^m}{n}\right) \tag3
> $$

where $P_m$ is a polynomial of degree $m$. **The above result is proved by Ph. Flajolet and R. Sedgewick in this remarkable [paper](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/inria-00074439/document)** (pp. 6-7, 1995) where an explicit form of $P_m$ is given.

For example, we have, as $n \to \infty$,

> $$
> \begin{align}
> -\sum_{k=1}^n({-1})^k{n\choose k}\frac1{k^2}=\frac12 (\log n)^2+\gamma \log n+C_2+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{(\log n)^2}{n}\right) \tag4
> \end{align}
> $$

or

> $$
> \begin{align}
> &-\sum_{k=1}^n({-1})^k{n\choose k}\frac1{k^3}\\&=\frac16 (\log n)^3+\frac{\gamma}2 (\log n)^2+\left(\frac{\gamma^2}2+\frac{\pi^2}{12}\right) \log n+C_3+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{(\log n)^3}{n}\right) \tag5
> \end{align}
> $$

where $C_1,C_2$ are constants and $\gamma$ denotes the Euler-Mascheroni constant.

Answer (score 0):

I can show that
if $m \ge n-3$,
then terms of the sum
decrease in absolute value,
so the sum of the series
is between
the first two partial sums,
i.e.,
$-n$
and
$-n+\frac{n(n-1)}{2\ 2^m}
=-n(1-\frac{n-1}{2^{m+1}})
$.

$S_{n,m}
=\sum_{k=1}^n({-1})^k{n\choose k}k^{-m}
$

If
$r_k
={n\choose k}k^{-m}
$,

$\begin{array}\\
s_k
&=\frac{r_{k+1}}{r_k}\\
&=\frac{{n\choose k+1}(k+1)^{-m}}{{n\choose k}k^{-m}}\\
&=\frac{\frac{n!}{(k+1)!(n-k-1)!}}{\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}}\frac{k^m}{(k+1)^m}\\
&=\frac{n-k}{k+1}\frac{1}{(1+1/k)^m}\\
\end{array}
$

If $s_k < 1$,
then the series is alternating
with decreasing terms,
so is bounded
between consecutive partial sums.

For $k \ge n/2$,
$s_k < 1$.

Also,
since
$(1+1/k)^m
> 1+m/k
$,
$s_k
<\frac{n-k}{k+1}\frac{1}{1+m/k}
=\frac{n-k}{k+1}\frac{k}{k+m}
$,
so $s_k < 1$
if
$k(n-k)
<(k+1)(k+m)
$
or
$kn-k^2
<k^2+(m+1)k+m
$
or
$2k^2+(m+1-n)k+m
> 0
$
or
$k(2k+m+1-n)+m
> 0
$.

Therefore
if $m \ge n-3$,
$s_k < 1$,
so the terms in
$S_{m, n}$
decrease in absolute value.
Therefore
the sum is between any two
consecutive partial sums,
so
$S_{n, m}$
is certainly bounded.